# Phonegap project doesn't compile

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

If I create a new Phonegap project, like this:

```
phonegap create . com.something.test "Test"
phonegap build android
```

And then import this into Android Studio, via "Import Project" -> "Create project from existing sources" -> Next (lots of times) -> Finish, and then just try to build without any modifications, I get this:

```
Error:(4, 14) java: duplicate class: org.apache.cordova.BuildConfig
```

Am I missing a step or is there an issue with Cordova 3.6.3 / Android Studio 0.5.1 ?

Comment: Painstakingly updated to Android Studio 0.9.3 and the latest Android API's (painstaking because the IDE seems buggy when trying to use Project Settings -> SDK's -- it's taken a while to hook API 14 - 21 up again without the build targets resetting to 'none'...). The result is the same error as above, so we can cancel out the possibility of this being an Android Studio issue I think.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, from Project Settings -> Modules, I analysed CordovaLib and Android Studio told me there was no dependancy for it, so I chose to remove. Now compilation seems to work!

I'm not sure why this needs removing but hopefully it'll help someone else too.